# Importing python files containing classes in site-packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, import, python-import

Disclaimer: I am not a Python expert, I am aware that this might have been asked before but I wasn't able to find it (or realize I had found it).

**THE AIM**:

I have created a Python program which consists of 3 Python files, `Qm_op.py`, `Qm_basis.py` and `Hamiltonian_1d_Spin.py` (each containing a class) which run correctly on their own. These Python files live in the

```
C:\Users\FriendlyLagrangian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\qusim
```

directory (`qusim` is supposed to be the name of the package) so that Python can always find it with `import` from anywhere. The aim is to be able to use this package anywhere else by doing

```
import qusim
```

just like I would do for `numpy`.

**WHAT WORKS:**

If I create a new Python file anywhere, or run a Python terminal containing the following code

```
>>> import qusim
>>> qusim
 <module 'qusim' from 'C:\\Users\\FriendlyLagrangian\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\qusim\\__init__.py'>
```

it seems like at least something is working okay. (As you can see, I have also an empty `__init__.py` in the same directory).

**WHAT DOESNT WORK:**

If I create a new file somewhere, and I try

```
>>> import qusim
>>> basis = Qm_basis(3,2)
```

just like it would work if I was writing it beneath the class `Qm_basis` in the file `Qm_basis.py` I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    basis = Qm_basis(3,2)
NameError: name 'Qm_basis' is not defined
```

which is no bueno. However, if I run

```
>>> from qusim import Qm_basis
>>> basis  = Qm_basis.Qm_basis(3,2)
>>> basis.bin
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]] (i.e. this is correct output)
```

success! But is ugly and not working as I've read a package should (syntax wise at least). Interestingly, running something similar yields

```
>>> from qusim import Qm_basis
>>> basis  = Qm_basis(3,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    basis  = Qm_basis(3,2)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

Upon reading I have tried many things, from playing with all possible permutations of `from`, `import` and my files names to modify the content of `__init__.py` but none work. I am also very puzzled with why [this apparently works](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/) but mine doesnt.

Thank you so much for your time I am really stuck!

Comment: I am aware I might be using the term "package" wrong and that it might be "library" or "module" but again I am unsure of their differences.

Comment: `from qusim.Qm_basis import Qm_basis` and then `Qm_basis(3,2)` ?

Comment: @progmatico This seems to be working! I'll update if I find further issues with these pesky imports.

Comment: @progmatico , btw why does it work? what does that `.` represent? they all are in the same folder no?

Comment: It means: import the name `Qm_basis` from the module (with the same name) `Qm_basis`, that is found inside the package `qusim`.

Comment: @progmatico So here the last `Qm_basis` refers to the **class** `Qm_basis` located in module `Qm_basis` right? so if I had more classes in that same module it would be `from qusim.Qm_basis import SomeOtherClass`? Lastly, how come `numpy` is simply imported by `import numpy` and everything works (unlike my case)?

Comment: Yes and yes. You can also list several comma separated names or specify * (not recommended) to import all the available names there. The from clause imports specific names into your current namespace, while `import something` makes the the names inside the package or module available through the reference `something` via dot notation.

Comment: If you want a better naming scheme for referring to your package names without changing its current internal structure , go to the package root `__init__.py`  and write there the required imports for all the names you want to make available under `qusim`. Write the imports to make the names directly available in the `__init__.py`outer scope. Try again importing from your scripts. The `__init__.py` runs and those names should be available via `qusim.somename` in your scripts (or directly if you use `from`).

Comment: @progmatico Thank you so much for your help! Would it be okay if I summarise all your comments in a answer below so that somebody else may learn from my question? I will of course "reference" your comments!

Comment: Yes of course! Be aware that the usual etiquette is the reverse,  to ask for the commentator to do that, and then you accept the answer, in order for him to benefit from the accepted answer and eventual later upvotes. Having the care of explaining it correctly may even help you to memorize what you learnt if you want to do it. This is more or less about import basics, that is why I only commented. That gives the chance for others to write answers and get upvoted. Welcome to Stack Overflow.! Put it right and I will upvote you too! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).